# how to show Read More button if text length exceeds more than 2 lines in Expo React Native App

Tags: android, ios, react-native, text, export

How can I show Read more button in Text if text length exceeds more than 2 lines? On Click of that **Read more** button a custom popup will be shown where full text will be visible. I have searched and checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51610538/is-it-possible-to-know-how-many-lines-of-text-are-rendered-by-react-native-when/51612098), [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2496), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38386704/react-native-determine-number-of-lines-of-text-component), but didn't found any proper solution to show Read more button as per requirement.

I tried this solution attached.. But here if I fixes numberOfLines to a value then "e.nativeEvent.lines.length" returns fixed value and if don't fixes numberOfLines then it returns complete text with ReadMore button which is wrong.

```
const ReadMore = props => {
    const [showMore, setShowMore] = useState(false)

    const longText = 'Nature, in the broadest sense, is the natural, physical, or material world or universe. "Nature" can refer to the phenomena of the physical world, and also to life in general. The study of nature is a large, if not the only, part of science. Although humans are part of nature, human activity is often understood as a separate category from other natural phenomena.'

    return (
        <View style={{
            margin: 20,
        }}>
            <Text
                numberOfLines={2}
                onTextLayout={(e) => setShowMore(e.nativeEvent.lines.length > 2)}
            >{longText}</Text>
            {showMore && (
                <Text style = {{color: 'blue'}} onPress = {() =>{
                    //Read more text action
                }}>Read More...</Text>
            )}
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: You can use [This](https://github.com/expo/react-native-read-more-text) library

Comment: @RutvikBhatt I have already checked it. There is show more, less options in this and it's handling action by self but I want to show popup instead of it.

Comment: @PiyushNaredi Please add your code

Comment: @PiyushNaredi btw, here I answered a question how to the get the current amount of lines in a TextInput, I think that should give you the idea: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56663069/how-to-get-the-current-number-of-lines-in-string-of-textinput/56663717#56663717

Comment: @Tim, this solution will work in case of textInput where numberofLines is calculated based on user entered text. But here in my case text is fixed & it's setted on Text component. How number of lines can be calculated in that case?

Comment: @Tim, I have added code which I tried but It didn't work.